# Grab largest image on site given the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given a URL how do I pull the largest image (in terms of image-dimensions) on the site? I am using it to act as the best possible representation of a sites thumbnail.

Similar to first thumbnail image when sharing a url on Facebook:

http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=my_website_url

The image thumbnail on Facebook in the div:

```
<div class="UIThumbPager_Thumbs">
```

Current code (using Javascript and JQuery):

```
else if (item.link) historyHtml += '<a href=' + item.link + ' class="image" target="_blank"><img src="*SITE THUMBNAIL HERE*" width="111px"></a>';
```

Please note, the user will be logged in to Facebook and will be able to access that site thumbnail.

Comment: is it using javascript,jquery or php ?

Comment: Hi JapanPro, I am using javascript and jquery.

Comment: Hi JapanPro, please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I re-asked the question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622144/pulling-share-thumbnail-given-url-from-facebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it on the client-side (i.e., with JavaScript) due to cross-domain restrictions. You'd need to download the contents of the URL on the back end first. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: How about using getElementById("img")?

Comment: How is that going to work when your "img" is on a remote site?

Comment: I think you mean `getElementsByTagName`, and that would still work only if the site was in the same domain.

Comment: @jprim you'll need a server side script acting as a proxy to do this.

Comment: Hi Pekka, what if I just pull the image thumbnail Facebook creates for a URL as described above?

Answer (score 1):

"Largest" image in filesize or image-dimensions? You'll have to parse the URLs code, extract all images and get the size. If you mean the image-dimensions, you can do it with JavaScript (create a new image from the img-source and use `img.width` and `img.height`), but for the filesize, you'll probably end up downloading all images to determine which on is the largest.

Comment: I mean the largest in terms of image-dimension. It gives the best representation of the site for a thumbnail. Or how about just pulling the Facebook thumbnail it generates for the URL for instance?

Comment: `just pulling the Facebook thumbnail it generates for the URL` ... ?? You may want to explain that in detail or (even better) put it in a separate question, as this seems to be something very different from your original question. Right now I don't really now what you're after.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am looking to pull the site thumbnail generated on:
http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=my_website_url
When passing a URL through it (as described above using item.link).
Please let me know if you have any other questions. Thank you!

Comment: Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: It is always the image in <div class="UIThumbPager_Thumbs">

Comment: I can't open your URL as it needs a login and I'm not on facebook, but again: pull the source code, parse it and grab the image. Shouldn't be much of a problem as you know it's always in the same DIV. (And still: your question doesn't reflect what you're actually looking for)

Comment: That is what I am asking to do. How do I pull the source code, parase it and grab the image? I updated the question, thanks.