# How do I extract the largest image (by dimension) on a site given the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For instance, if I input:
http://www.google.com/

It would return:
http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png

Using javascript/jquery. These sites would all be external. Thank you!

Comment: you have asked the exact same question some time ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615983/grab-largest-image-on-site-given-the-url - why again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since that is a Google Chrome extension, you are not bound to same origin policy.

Basically, you would need [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to fetch all the images within a page, and check each image's size within the DOM to know if its larger the last fetched image.

You can use [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html), to communicate from the Content Script to the popup/background page.

For example, I will show you how to get the largest image from a page and show it within the popup. We use all the techniques shown above and  you will see the largest image within the popup if you activate it. (should show I believe :))

### manifest.json (snippet)

```
 ...

 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "http://*/*"
 ],
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js": ["images.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": true
  }
 ]

...
```

### popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getImage() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getImage"}, function (response) {
      var text = document.getElementById('image'); 
      var image = response.data;
      text.src = image ? response.data : 'no_image.gif';
    });
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="getImage(); ">Get Largest Image</button>
<img src="no_image.gif" id="image"/>
</body>
</html>
```

### images.js (content script)

```
function getMaxImage() {
  var maxDimension = 0;
  var maxImage = null;

  // Iterate through all the images.
  var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var index in imgElements) {
    var img = imgElements[index];
    var currDimension = img.width * img.height;
    if (currDimension  > maxDimension){
       maxDimension = currDimension
       maxImage = img;
    }
  }
  // Check if an image has been found.
  if (maxImage) 
    return maxImage.src;
  else
    return null;
}

// Listen for extension requests.
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method == "getImage") {
    sendResponse({data: getMaxImage()});
  } else {
    sendResponse({}); // snub them.
  }
});
```

Comment: though it's an old answer, but you can use `document.images` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` :)

Answer (score 5):

This is more web-scraping than JavaScript/jQuery.

However, given an assumption that you've received the HTML, and that it is available somehow in a JavaScript string, then something like the following might suffice for finding the maximum dimension image:

```
var sHTML = getHTMLSomehow(sURL);
var nMaxDim = 0;
var $pageDOM = $(sHTML);
var $objMaxDimImage;

$pageDOM.("img").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var nDim = parseFloat($this.width()) * parseFloat($(this).height());
    if (nDim > nMaxDim){
        $objMaxDimImage = $this;
        nMaxDim = nDim
    }
});

alert("Max dim is:" nMaxDim);
alert("Image Source:" $objMaxDimImage.attr("src"));
```

Answer (score 2):

due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you cant access an external site with javascript. maybe you can write a server-side script that downloads the page (for example using `wget`), search for img-tags in the html code and load all found images to check the size.